# Internet capped to 9mb/s on my pc. Other family members get the maximum of 20 mb/s

Tags: internet, ethernet, bandwidth

my internet is setup as shows.
main router to wireless WiFi extender. Ethernet cable from WiFi extender to PC

Comment: There's no "shown", and we will need to know more about your setup - for example, what is the 802.11 subversion of your WiFi, how is your family connecting, etc.

Comment: WiFi is slower than Ethernet. It could also be set to Half Duplex instead of Full Duplex which cuts your speed in half. What are your network settings?